How to best prep the transition from cement board to door frame in a bathroom?
I'm actively renovating the bathroom in my 1950's home and need to learn how to prep the transition between the cement board of our tub/shower surround and the door frame directly next to the tub.


If this context is helpful, there's 3 inches between the tub and the door frame.
It's not shown in the pictures, but I've already taped and applied thinset to the seams of the cement board, but I did not apply tape and thinset to the transition between the cement board and door frame since I wasn't sure if that was a good idea. I didn't know if the expansion and contraction of the door frame would cause issues with the thinset if I taped and applied thinset to that joint.
Is that the best course of action, or should I do something else for this transition?
For context, once I address the transition to the door frame, I plan on waterproofing the cement board with RedGard and then I need to decide whether I need to bring the tile all the way out to the door frame and have the tile serve as the door trim on that left side of the door, install vinyl trim of some sort, or do something else.
That's a question for another day and probably another forum since it may be too opinion based.
Today, I'm mostly hoping to learn how to best address the transition from the Durock to the wooden door frame so I can move on to applying the RedGard.

Please tell us what the intended wall finish is around the tub and what the intended finish will be between the tub and the door frame.

What is the distance between the outside of the door jamb and the face of the tub apron?

@DelphicOracle Good question! We intend to tile the tub surround and bring the tile out just past the cement board to overlap the transition to the wall above the door, potentially using bullnose tile trim or a Schluter RONdec tile edging.
In between the tub apron and the door, it depends on the door trim solution we land on, but based on the answer RMDman provided below, we may use PVC trim, which means we'll need small pieces of tile to make up the gap between the tub apron and the trim that covers the door frame.

@Huesmann Good question, the distance between the face of the tub apron and outside of the door jamb is 3 inches. The distance of that space varies slightly from 3 1/16th in. at the floor to 3 3/16th in. at the tub deck.

That spacing seems like you could fit a standard door casing.  Perhaps you could simply push your tile above to the casing, and caulk between the tub and casing?

How to address the gap is directly related to the decision you make in materials to cover the door frame.
The customary method would be to use door casing around the door and the gap will be covered.  Nothing else is needed to be done with the gap. PVC casing is available at most big box stores and lumber yards, if you are concerned about humidity.
If you decide to tile to the edge of the door frame, other issues come up.
How is the tile terminating at the edge? Do you plan schluter jolly or something similar?  If you cover the gap and leave a normal 1/4" reveal you can put some caulking in the gap and tile over it.
This will look odd with the top and opposing side of the door having casing. But it is your house. Cracks in the grout from expansion and contraction of dissimilar materials can happen.
From experience, plan to use casing all around the door frame. Run the tile to the outer edge of the frame and use aluminium trim (like jolly) to finish the edge above the door .
It is the easiest thing to do and will have the most pleasing aesthetic, ( unless you like weird things)

That's really helpful. Thank you!
The previous shower system was essentially full-wall sized tiles, and they used an 8' x ~2.5" piece of tile to cover the door jamb and the transition between the shower and wall above the door. Like you mentioned in your answer, the top of the door trim terminated into this tile trim and it did look odd, so going with traditional door casing may be the way to go.
In addition to humidity, I'm also worried about periodic water splashes since the tub will mostly be used by our 2 young children, so the PVC trim sounds like it would be a good option.

If we go with using door casing on all three sides, what would you recommend I do about the gap between the cement board and drywall above the door? Should I use tape and thinset to bridge that gap prior to applying the RedGard on the rest of the cement board on the tub surround?

Yes, you need to tape and mud all the seams, even those that will be covered with tile. The one above the door and any others that will be seen need to be made smooth. (Like wall to ceiling.) The seams that will be covered behind tile don't have to be so pretty.

Don't stress about the RedGuard up high. I stop my waterproofing about an inch from the ceiling and the outer edge of where I plan to tile.  I know of some guys that stop at about 6 feet.
